# Browse Nautilus Bookmarks folder from command line

Tags: 14.04, nautilus

I share a network folder from Ubuntu machine#1 to Ubuntu machine#2

In machine#2 I can use Nautilus to browse that shared folder in machine#1. I can add that folder to Bookmarks.

How should I browse that shared folder from command line? Seems like I may try to manually add an entry to `fstab`. But given the `Bookmarks` folder seems to be already existent in Nautilus, is there a way to browse to that Bookmarks folder from the command line?

Comment: Not sure how much this would help, but from http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67350/can-i-access-nautiluss-bookmarks-in-terminal, the Nautilus bookmarks are located at `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

Comment: @edwinksl thanks. I checked that bookmark file, it doesn't contain an entry for for my network shared folder, not sure why. It only has some entries starting with `file:///home/etc.`